# Bad SVG output when using htlatex

Tags: html, svg, htlatex

I am trying to compile some minimal `test.tex` using `htlatex test.tex "xhtml,svg"`, but the SVG generated from tikz pictures does not seem to work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Testing}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Inline equation \(X_1 + X_2 = Y\), equation
\[\int^{X \in \mathbf{C}} \mathbf{C}(X,X).
\]

Tikz picture.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [blue,fill] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  \draw [red,fill] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The svg file for the tikz picture seems to be generated in a different way from the other SVGs (it has a different name scheme from the others, for instance), and it does not display due to the following error.

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </g>.
Location: file:///home/mario/testing-htlatex/test-1.svg
Line Number 5, Column 3:
</p><g stroke="#000" fill="#000">
```

Indeed, removing that conflicting `<p>` makes the SVG display again. Is this a bug or am I missing something? Did I do something wrong that added that `<p>` to the tikz picture? Why is the tikz picture generated differently?

What puzzles me the most is that, if I decide to try without svg, using just `htlatex test.tex`, then a correct SVG for the tikz picture gets generated (!).

Comment: Oh, so it works if I enclose the tikzpicture with `\[...\]`. Was this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, TikZ uses special driver for TeX4ht to create the SVG file. It maps the low-level PGF command to SVG, so it doesn't use the mechanism TeX4ht uses for the conversion of LaTeX code to SVG. Sometimes this method fails. You can use the [alternative TikZ driver for TeX4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht). It uses `dvisvgm` for the conversion to SVG. It results in better results in most cases (but there are cases where it fails completely). It seems to work nice for your example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\ifdefined\HCode
   \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Testing}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Inline equation \(X_1 + X_2 = Y\), equation
\[\int^{X \in \mathbf{C}} \mathbf{C}(X,X).
\]

Tikz picture.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [blue,fill] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  \draw [red,fill] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You may also want to use [make4ht](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html) instead of `htlatex`. It fixes lot of issues that `htlatex` has and provides additional features.

This is the result when I compile your document using

```
make4ht filename.tex "svg"
```

[image]

Comment: I see. I must be doing something wrong because your exact code (having downloaded the alternative driver, also using make4ht) generates a blank svg in place of the tikzpicture (maybe this is a problem of dvisvgm?).  In any case, putting every tikz inside an equation works perfectly. Thank you, @michal.h21

Comment: @MarioRomán you should see some info from dvisvgm in the terminal output. maybe there are some error messages?